# Коллекция как DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Создал коллекцию элементов. На всякий случай напихал в нее кучу интерфейсов (потом уберу ненужные)

```
public class HighlightRulesCollection : DependencyObject, ICollection<HighlightRule>, INotifyCollectionChanged, ICollection, ICollectionViewFactory, IList, IList<HighlightRule>, IAddChild
```

Суть в том, чтобы у меня была возможность определять коллекцию в ресурсах и потом использовать как `StaticResources`. Но вот беда! Все, что я добавляю в эту коллекцию в xaml разметке, реально в нее не добавляется. То есть после инициализации коллекции она пуста. В чем может быть дело?

**UPD:**

Вот коллекция в ресурсах

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:HighlightRulesCollection x:Key="hlRules">
        <local:HighlightRule HightlightedText="qwe">
            <local:HighlightRule.Highlights>
                <local:HighlightBackgroung Brush="Yellow"/>
                <local:HighlightForeground/>
            </local:HighlightRule.Highlights>
        </local:HighlightRule>
    </local:HighlightRulesCollection>
</Window.Resources>
```

Вот на нее биндинг (в том же окне)

```
<local:HighlightTextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Property}"
                          HighlightRules="{StaticResource hlRules}">
```

А вот что в обозревателе свойств (во время выполнения)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно, коллекция есть, она нужного типа, но она пустая.

Для примера вот с соседнего контрола скрин (в него я непосредственно добавил элементы коллекции)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не создаются ли случайно разные коллекции? то есть одна в коде, а другая в `xaml`

Comment: @S.Kost, почитайте обновление.

Comment: У вас два варианта сразу `ICollection<HighlightRule>` и `IList<HighlightRule>`, попробуйте убрать  `ICollection<HighlightRule>`. Должно заработать

Comment: @S.Kost, не помогло

Comment: @iRumba: А не может быть такого случайно, что у вас один из контролов убирает элементы из коллекции? Коллекция-то у вас общая.

Comment: @VladD, snoop показал, что в коллекции таки есть эелементы, однако биндинг в данном случае работает очень странно. Я же правильно делаю, что связываю HighlightRulesCollection и HighlightRulesCollection ? Таргет же должен подтянуть элементы из сурса? Я запутался уже

Comment: @VladD, поставил точку останова на `static void HighlightRulesChanged` (это коллбэк на изменение DP). Сначала мне приходит null (по дефолту, видимо), потом приходит новое свойство без элементов (видимо то, которое создается в конструкторе). А `HighlightRules="{StaticResource hlRules}"` результатов не приносит. Походу я все таки где то ошибся, но не могу понять где.